# How to click an element that updates every couple seconds [SELENIUM CHROME C#]

Tags: c#, selenium

So I am trying to make a script that navigates to a website and clicks on links that update every 5-10 seconds or so. Problem is I am using a div selector to get the most recent link and since the div constantly changes with the updated link I am at a loss on how to point selenium to the most recent link.

i would just parse the whole HTML for the first link in the stack but unfortunately that doesn't lead me to the content that I want so I have to dive into the div and get a link under the  tag. Anyway to do this in Selenium?

Current code as of right now to select the top most div:

```
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[6]//a")).Click();
```

This only gets the most recent and won't update to get the most updated link from the most recent div

Comment: Can you post the HTML or link to the page you are trying to automate? And possibly the rest of your code sample too? It's hard to visualize what's happening here with just the problem description & one line of code you are using.

Comment: Please post the html source and we can then come up with the best xpath

Comment: just a suggestion, never use the xpath that chrome supplies. It is the most brittle xpath you can write and you will constantly find yourself fixing it. Go directly to the source of the link and find it by class, id, text, preceding-sibling, following-sibling whatever it takes. Check out this site for xpath help -  https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your xPath is wrong.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[6]/a[1]")).Click()
```

This will work if you mapped element correctly.

Comment: if I use this code will it update to the new Divs being created on the page?

Comment: `/html/body/div[6]//a` is not inherently wrong, it will still find `a` elements on the page, it just might not be the right one(s) that the original asker is looking for. It's hard to determine if `/html/body/div[6]/a[1]` is correct without seeing more details about the page they are automating.

Comment: Could you at least copy&paste html source code? Because, we are not sure your xPath is correct or not.

Comment: Well Christine, it is wrong technically syntax may be correct but in real life: this useage means that find an <a> element in page and click on it, I guess no one wants these kind of blindfolded approach in his/her code.

Comment: @furkanayd No Christine is correct, it finds <a> element AFTER it has found /html/body/div[6]

Answer (score 0):

With very limited information requesting you to please try below code :

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement element= wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Xpath("/html/body/div[6]//a[1]")));

element.Click();
```